# How to create tokens from R code implemented in R

Tags: r, lexical-analysis

This is the code:

```
aggregate(results ~ school, FUN = table, data = df)
```

The above code is written in R. Is there any tool available in R to extract tokens so above becomes:

```
FUNC_NAME(DATA ~ DATA, PARA_FUN = DATA, PARA_DATA = DATA)
```

I tried [minilexer](https://coolbutuseless.bitbucket.io/2018/03/26/parsing-data-part-1.-the-minilexer-package---a-simple-lexer-in-r/) to split some simplified R code into tokens. But the rules are really simple. I'm wondering if there is any tool that have implemented all rules already, so I don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Not exactly what you are searching for, but the package `pryr` might interest you. Try `pryr::ast(aggregate(results ~ school, FUN = table, data = df))`..

Comment: @symbolrush Thanks! This is cool but not what I am looking for though. I need to get tokens with their type info, such as literal, parameter.

Comment: You can play with the result of `lapply(quote(EXPR), class)`. However, note that things like argument names have no direct equivalence in R’s AST representation of expressions since they operate on a higher level than the raw tokens.

Comment: @KonradRudolph So actually it contains the argument names "FUN" and "data", but the full result is just: name, call, name (FUN), and name (data), which is not what I need exactly, and missing other stuff. But thanks for letting me know about this from R base though.

Comment: @MrFlick This is nice! I will need to parse the resulting table from this, but feeling like a good starting point! Btw, I'm just curious if there is any existing tool to do lexical tokenization for R code, so that I can just grab something off the shelf.

Comment: @Sean Those are the argument *values*, not the argument names. The argument names aren’t represented as items in the AST, they are attributes (= names) on specific AST nodes.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Got it! Do you know if there is any existing package to do lexical tokenization in R, since internally they have enough info there, right?

Comment: @Sean The “parser” package does, but the information it provides is exactly the same as that provided by `getParseData` from MrFlick’s comment. So I think that’s the best you can get.

Comment: @MrFlick I looked into this and it is actually what I need. I will work my way onto twisting what you provided. Wish I could upvote you :)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Nice, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the results from the R lexer using

```
getParseData(parse(text="aggregate(results ~ school, FUN = table, data = df)"))

#    line1 col1 line2 col2 id parent                token terminal      text
# 27     1    1     1   51 27      0                 expr    FALSE          
# 1      1    1     1    9  1      3 SYMBOL_FUNCTION_CALL     TRUE aggregate
# 3      1    1     1    9  3     27                 expr    FALSE          
# 2      1   10     1   10  2     27                  '('     TRUE         (
# 10     1   11     1   26 10     27                 expr    FALSE          
# 4      1   11     1   17  4      6               SYMBOL     TRUE   results
# 6      1   11     1   17  6     10                 expr    FALSE          
# 5      1   19     1   19  5     10                  '~'     TRUE         ~
# 7      1   21     1   26  7      9               SYMBOL     TRUE    school
# 9      1   21     1   26  9     10                 expr    FALSE          
# 8      1   27     1   27  8     27                  ','     TRUE         ,
# 13     1   29     1   31 13     27           SYMBOL_SUB     TRUE       FUN
# 14     1   33     1   33 14     27               EQ_SUB     TRUE         =
# 15     1   35     1   39 15     17               SYMBOL     TRUE     table
# 17     1   35     1   39 17     27                 expr    FALSE          
# 16     1   40     1   40 16     27                  ','     TRUE         ,
# 20     1   42     1   45 20     27           SYMBOL_SUB     TRUE      data
# 21     1   47     1   47 21     27               EQ_SUB     TRUE         =
# 22     1   49     1   50 22     24               SYMBOL     TRUE        df
# 24     1   49     1   50 24     27                 expr    FALSE          
# 23     1   51     1   51 23     27                  ')'     TRUE         )
```

Internally it looks like R is using the [Bison lexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Bison). The grammar it uses is defined in the [gram.y](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/gram.y) file of the source code. You should be able to get all the information you need from that. It's better to rely on the built-in lexer rather than having a package try to re-implement the build in one

Comment: Very useful! Is there something like a "token reference"? For example, a description of how `SYMBOL_SUB` differs from `SYMBOL` etc. I checked out some Bison pages, but haven't found a lot.

Comment: @jakub The gram.y file defines the specific grammar to R. The term SYMBOL_SUB is an R thing, not a general Bison thing. I don't know of any documentation other than the code itself. The different in this case is that SYMBOL_SUB is for parameter names and EQ_SUM is for the equals used with name parameters. These behave differently than regular symbols and equals signs because they are not evaluated or assigned so they have a special class.